# Change tuples in a tuple to lists in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to remove tuples from a list, but I have no idea what to do.

I want to change this:

```
((1947, '23:53'), (1949, '23:57'))
```

into this:

```
[[1947, '23:53'], [1949, '23:57']]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions to the rescue! You're basically just spinning through the list of tuples and casting them to a list, creating a new list while doing so.

```
list_of_tuples = [(1,2), (3,4)]
list_of_lists = [list(my_tuple) for my_tuple in list_of_tuples]
```